# Multiple serveResource methods in liferay mvc portlet

Tags: liferay-7

How can i Do multiple serveResource methods in normal liferay mvc portlet(i know in spring mvc )
give me any example if you have.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  Add the below code in JSP

```
<portlet:resourceURL id="/server/resource/one" var="oneURL" />
<portlet:resourceURL id="/server/resource/two" var="twoURL" />
```

Step 2: Create Class and implement "MVCResourceCommand"

```
    @Component(
    immediate = true,
    property = {
        "javax.portlet.name=your_portlet_name_YourPortlet",
        "mvc.command.name=/server/resource/one"
    },
    service = MVCResourceCommand.class
)
public class YourMVCResourceCommand implements MVCResourceCommand {
    // your resource handling code
}
```

The property "mvc.command.name" to the value of the id property in your JSP’s must be match.

Check this link for more infromation: https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018159491-MVC-Resource-Command